# Filetype PDF is not getting uploaded through Antd upload

Tags: reactjs, pdf, react-hooks, antd

While using Ant design upload component, pdf file is not getting uploaded and throwing `dropdown.pdf file upload failed` as error.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Upload , message, Button }  from 'antd';
import { UploadOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

const Dropdown = () => {
    const props = {
        name: 'file',
        action: 'https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76',
        accept: ".pdf",
        onChange(info) {
          if (info.file.status !== 'uploading') {
            console.log(info.file, info.fileList);
          }
      
          if (info.file.status === 'done') {
            message.success(`${info.file.name} file uploaded successfully`);
          } else if (info.file.status === 'error') {
            message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
          }
        },
      };
    
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>
                Dropdown
            </h1>
            <div>
                <Upload {...props} accept='.doc,.docx,application/pdf'>
                    <Button
                        accept={[".pdf"]} icon={<UploadOutlined />}
                    >
                        Click to Upload
                    </Button>
                    <p>Choose file to upload</p>
                </Upload> 
                <Button onClick={fetch}>
                    Upload
                </Button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DropDown
```

I have tried other methods and help from youtube and [this repository by HamzaAnwar](https://github.com/HamzaAnwar1998/Upload-View-Pdf-In-Reactjs) even couldn't solve my problem. I will welcome any answers for uploading files through antd in reactjs.

Comment: Looks like `action: 'https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76'` is giving some issue, what response are you getting?